# How to repeat an animation certain number of time?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have an `AnimationController` object and I want to repeat an animation 10 times.

```dart
AnimationController controller = ...;
controller.repeat(count: 10); // Wish there was something like this
```

---

**Note**: I'm not looking for workarounds, like calling `controller.forward(from: 0)` 10 times recursively or `Timer.periodic`, or keeping a count of `AnimationController.animationStatus`, etc and then stopping the animation.

Comment: check `SawTooth` with `int count` set to 10

Comment: @pskink Perfect, this is it. Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: feel free to write a self-answer ;-)

Comment: @pskink Just did. Once again thanks so much for your support :)

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink).

You need to use `SawTooth` curve and set the `count`. For example:

```dart
FadeTransition(
  opacity: CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: SawTooth(10)), 
  child: SomeChild(),
);
```